# How Do I Setup SonarQube cfamil.gcov Correctly?

Tags: c++, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan, gcov

I cannot get coverage reporting to work within SonarQube.  I have a C++ project for which I am using the build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 along with the sonar-scanner.  The basic static analysis for the source code seems to work but there is nothing about test code coverage reported within SonarQube.

As part of the same workflow I am using lcov and genhtml to make a unit test coverage report, so I am confident that most of the code coverage steps are being correctly executed.  When I manually view the .gcov files I can see run counts in the first column, so there is data there.

I have my code organised into modules.  The sonar-project.properties file includes the following:

```
# List of the module identifiers
sonar.modules=Module1,Module2

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set.
sonar.sources=./Sources,./Tests
HeliosEmulator.sonar.sources=./Application,./Sources,./Tests
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=build_output

# Existing reports
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=build_output
#sonar.cfamily.cppunit.reportsPath=junit
sonar.cfamily.gcov.reportsPath=.
#sonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=cppcheck-result-1.xml
#sonar.cxx.xunit.reportPath=cpputest_*.xml
sonar.junit.reportPaths=junit
```

I would also like to get the unit test results displayed under the Sonar tools.  As I am using the CppUTest framework I do not have an xunit or junit test output at present though.  This can be dealt with as a separate issue but as I am unable to found much documentation of how to use the cfamily scanner online I do not know if the tests not being listed is relevant.

Comment: I have also posted this question to the Sonar Qube user community on Google Groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/0MXZP0pn8iA

Comment: I had forgotten to setup my CI system correctly.  The .gcov files did not exist for the job that was running the sonar-scanner.  They only existed in the testing job that generated the coverage report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to setup my CI system correctly. The .gcov files did not exist for the job that was running the sonar-scanner.  They only existed in the testing job that generated the coverage report.  No files in the scanner job mean it cannot make a coverage report.

When I set the GitLab CI system I am using to keep the .gcov files as artefacts the coverage reporting suddenly started working.

The .gcov files were generated by a test job and need to be transferred to the sonar-scanner job via the artefact store.  This is because GitLab CI does not share a work area between dependent jobs and you have to explicitly say what files must be copied.

Comment: Hi @TafT can you please give an example how did you do that?

Comment: What part do you need more details around?  If you already have lcov outputting a coverage report (which you can verify looks correct using genhtml) then then next step is to ensure the lcov report is passed corrected to the scanner using the sonar.cfamily.gcov.reportsPath=. property.  You will need to check the path names in the .gcov file match what SonarQube thinks the file paths are too, e.g. youd need to trim off /home/me/work/ or similar if that was in the file but not in SonarQube's view of the project.